# How to do self join in mongodb with laravel

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5

I am new in mongodb+laravel. I would like to a result of self join  in mongodb using laravel. At present I have provided

```
 $books = DB::table('books as a')
        ->Join('books as b', 'a.author', '!=', 'b.author')
        ->get();
```

but getting error. Could someone help me in this?

Comment: can you provide the mongodb version ?

Comment: @JensonRaby - its 3.0.9

Comment: in mongo 3.2.4 u got option for join using $lookup, u can try this [link] : (https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Comment: how to implement $lookup in laravel?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this query ?